# Host multiple sites on the same box

Tags: reverse-proxy, httpd, proxypass

I have multiple tools running on different ports on the same machine. Jenkins, gitea, etc. I have a CNAME setup for each. jenkins.foo.bar, gitea.foo.bar, etc. I'm trying to set it up so when I go to jenkins.foo.bar it actually loads foo.bar:8080 and gitea.foo.bar loads foo.bar:3000. So far I've tried to setup a proxy pass and reverse proxy pass with httpd 2.4.6.

```
<VirtualHost gitea.foo.bar:80>
ServerName gitea.foo.bar
ServerAlias gitea.foo.bar gitea.foo
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / foo.bar:3000/
ReverseProxyPass / foo.bar:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:
The actual question... Originally I was get Error 403 unavailable. Now when I go to gitea.foo it's redirected to foo.bar:3000 correctly. gitea.foo.bar loads foo.bar's index and is not caught by the proxy.

Part 2: Is it possible to keep gitea.foo in the address bar and not display the redirected address?

=========================

EDIT (The solution):
Big thanks to @GeraldSchneider

SeLinux was blocking proxy pass. Note this took 20 minutes to complete

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Move ssl.conf out of the way since it was listening on 443.

```
mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf /etc/hhtpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.bak
```

Add the following to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Listen 443 https
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName gitea.foo.bar
Redirect / httpd://gitea.foo.bar:3000
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName gitea.foo.bar
SSLEngine On
SSlProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/PATH/TO/gitea.foo.bar.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFIle /etc/PATH/TO/gitea.foo.bar.key
ProxyPass / https://gitea.foo.bar:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://gitea.foo.bar:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit gitea config /etc/gitea/app.ini

```
[server]
PROTOCOL = https
ROOT_URL = https://gitea.foo.bar
CERT_FILE = /etc/PATH/TO/gitea.foo.bar.pem
KEY_FILE = /etc/PATH/TO/gitea.foo.bar.key
```

Comment: That's a good start, but I don't see a question in there. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider updated with question

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache configuration is fine, the problem is your backend.

Your backend is configured for the URL `foo.bar:3000`, so it redirects there when it is NOT reached via this URL.

You need to configure your backend servers for the new URL. How to do this is different on every application server, a common name for such a setting is `base url` or something like this. Read the documentation of your backend servers (jenkins, gitea, etc ...) on how to do that.

Examples:

Jenkins: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221238/what-does-jenkins-url-means-in-configuration-settings

Gitea:

> set `[server] ROOT_URL = http://git.example.com/git/` in your configuration.

From: https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/reverse-proxies/

Comment: That makes sense. Will gitea.foo and gitea.foo.bar work when I do this?

Comment: Depends on your backend server. Some allow multiple URLs, most don't.

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference. When I got to gitea.foo it redirects to foo.bar:3000. I edited the gitea app.ini.

Comment: I'm all confused now. I removed the whole section from httpd.conf restarted httpd and it's still redirecting.

Comment: Firefox was caching my redirects. At one point I had a `redirect / foo.bar:3000`

Comment: Great that you found it! Please post it as an answer and accept it, so your question is marked as solved. I'm sure this will help others in the future as well

Comment: Finally figured it out. SeLinux was blocking the proxypass. I ended up using a redirect line instead. `redirect / foobar:3000`

Comment: Uhm, you only need to run `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` to allow Apache to act as proxy.

Comment: I tried that :( The setsebool command hangs forever

Comment: Finally got it working. The setsebool command took 20minutes to run. I had killed it long before that. If you open the question back up I can post my answer

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to reopen the question. I cast a reopen vote, currently there are 2 of the 5 needed votes. When it reopens and you post your answer don't forget to remove the solution from your question as well.